# trouble with get result by regular expressions from multiple urls

Tags: python, regex

I'm having trouble with get result by regular expressions from multiple urls.

for example

`https://test.net/best/18762.html`

regex

`\.net/best/([^\?#]+).html`

I can get `18762` as I wanted.

but this one (multiple urls like this):

`https://vsvs.cc/?page=324`

How do I only get `324` by regular expressions?

Comment: New URL doesn't have `.net` or `/best/` and it doesn't even end with `.html`. Why do you want to use a single regex for both different URLs?

Comment: @anubhava first one is an example. and second is for testing. I'll use new regex rule for second type of urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regex pattern of `(\d+)` would be enough to extract the numbers from the url.

```py
>>> url
'https://test.net/best/18762.html'
>>> re.search(r"(\d+)", url)
<re.Match object; span=(22, 27), match='18762'>
>>> url2
'https://vsvs.cc/?page=324'
>>> re.search(r"(\d+)", url2)
<re.Match object; span=(22, 25), match='324'>
```